# mysql: how do I ignore all rows that contain (value column A), if one of these rows has a specific value in column B?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I am looking for a way to filter not only the duplicate rows, but also the "initial" row. The goal is to have a clean list of all positions. The list is used by sales / accounting to see open positions, thats why the initial "Invoice" position has to be removed as well if a "Cancellcation" exists for that invoice.

I've tried solutions with group by, subqueries and EXISTS, but can't get the expected result. Ideally, I get this to work as an additional filter inside the where clause.

Default

| ID | Nr | Type | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NR-100 | Invoice | 100 |
| 2 | NR-101 | Invoice | 200 |
| 3 | NR-102 | Invoice | 300 |
| 4 | NR-100 | Cancellation | 100 |
| 5 | NR-102 | Cancellation | 300 |
| 6 | NR-103 | Invoice | 150 |

Expected results

| ID | Nr | Type | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | NR-101 | Invoice | 200 |
| 6 | NR-103 | Invoice | 150 |

Comment: Exists is probably what I would do..what problem did you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EXISTence test would seem to be the way to go so I wonder what problem you had with it..

```
select * 
from t 
where type = 'invoice' and 
not exists (select 1 from t t1 where t1.nr = t.nr and t1.type = 'cancellation')
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I tried something similar and ended up having the same result I am having now with your suggestion. It appears that as soon as it finds 1 row with cancellation (doesn't matter for which t1.nr) it will remove every invoice from the result.

At least that is my guess, can't really tell what exactly the problem is since I am a beginner.

Comment: select *
from
  easy_bill_bills ebb
where
  ebb.easy_bill_type = 'INVOICE'
  and not exists (
    select
      1
    from
      easy_bill_bills ebb2
    where
      ebb2.number = ebb2.number
      and ebb2.easy_bill_type = 'STORNO'
  )

It should definitely return a few Invoice entries, but its entirely empty (don't be confused about invoice and storno being in all caps, that is correct).

Comment: ebb2.easy_bill_type = 'STORNO ?? there is no type in your sample other than invoice and cancellation..And none of the column names match

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue.. https://dbfiddle.uk/paNu9x7v

Comment: Had another look and spotted my mistake! dbfiddle seems like a handy tool too!
(select 1 from t t1 where **t1.nr = t.nr** and t1.type = 'cancellation')
Here was my mistake. They can be the same table, but the reference changes. I guess that was why my earlier attempts with exists failed too. Thanks!!
For clarification I used t1.nr = t1.nr which in retrospective makes not a lot of sense.